# How to post video on twitter in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, twitter

I am an ios developer,i am working on app in which i needs to send video on twitter.But i searched and found that we can only post link of Video,but cannot post the video itself in iPhone sdk.

Can anyone suggest me what to do,if i need to post video on twitter.

Comment: You can easily send video on twitter by using ShareKit

Answer (score 0):

I just suggest you to look over the TwitVid documentation From bellow link:

http://twitvid.pbworks.com/w/page/22556295/FrontPage

**UPDATE:**

i use this type of logic in 4.3 with `shareKit`

```
        NSString *urlstr =[YorURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
        [urlstr retain];
        NSString *apiEndpoint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=%@",urlstr];
        [apiEndpoint retain];

        NSLog(@"\n\n APIEndPoint : %@",apiEndpoint);
        NSString *shortURL = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:apiEndpoint]
                                                      encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                         error:nil];
        [shortURL retain];
        NSLog(@"Long: %@ - Short: %@",urlstr,shortURL);


        NSString *txtShare=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You watching Your %@",shortURL];
        SHKItem  *item = [SHKItem text:txtShare];
        [SHK setRootViewController:self];
        [SHKTwitter shareItem:item];
```

hope this help you...

Comment: i also want to upload but its not working please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066213/how-to-upload-video-on-twitter-using-twitvid-in-iphone-sdk i have also posted my sample which is not working. Please help me

Comment: @ParasJoshi:- it's not working now so do you have any alternative solution for this?

Comment: @D-eptdeveloper now i have not other solution but bellow 5.0 you can use above method otherwise 5.0 and above provide inbuilt functionality.. see that above link .. in which iOS you want to use it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use TWRequest class with

```
 - (void)addMultiPartData:(NSData *)data withName:(NSString *)name type:(NSString *)type
```

I am not sure if uploading video is possible.

More on using TWRequest https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/posting-images-using-twrequest

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [the uploading media new API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/media/upload-chunked), you can share video to twitter. And I have tried it, it works.

Please check this: https://github.com/liu044100/SocialVideoHelper

You just need to call this class method.

```
+(void)uploadTwitterVideo:(NSData*)videoData account:(ACAccount*)account withCompletion:(dispatch_block_t)completion;
```

Hope it can resolve your problem.

Comment: Works perfect, but i'm searching for other way without twitter credentials in the device settings. You know other way?

Comment: @jose920405 It maybe need use other method that first get the user's Auth Token (maybe need a web view load twitter site and show login UI), and then call twitter's video API, I didn't try this yet, just a guess, feel very complicated...

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding, I found what I was looking at `twitterKit` first attempts to bring credentials settings, if not, does the application, and finally shows a modal to login out there