# how to upload video on twitter using twitvid in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, video, upload, twitter-oauth

I am trying to upload video to twitter using twitvid i got [sample code](http://twitvid.pbworks.com/w/file/fetch/61533948/TwitVid%20SDK.zip) from [TwitVid](http://twitvid.pbworks.com/w/page/22556295/FrontPage)
when i run the sample code and i tried to upload a video at that time it shows me uploading process in `UIAlertView` but after completion of uploading it gives me error `Upload Failed` i found that in this sample code `TwitVid_APP_ID` is missing but i tried a lot to get `TwitVid_APP_ID` from TwitVid but i didn't get a way to get `TwitVid_APP_ID`. I have also gone through the [document](http://twitvid.pbworks.com/w/page/22556300/Stream%20API%20Doc) of TwitVid they have mentioned that if you want to get `TwitVid_APP_ID` than mail at mailto:support@twitvid.com .i also mailed but its also not working.

I know how the `TwitPic` works for image uploading, but i am trying to upload video here.

Is there any other way to upload video on twitter than please also mention me.

can any body please help me?

Comment: you can only share the link of the video i guess and when user clicks on the link they will be redirected to the link of video and they can watch it. and the video link can be shared at the same way images shared.

Comment: @D-eptdeveloper yes i know that but i want to put functionality like user can press upload video and the video will be uploaded directly to user twitter account and link will be automatically created. like this application https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/twitvid/id317646079?mt=8

Answer (score 2):

Try this

step 1: **https://dev.twitter.com/apps**

step 2: login your twitter account

step 3: click **create a  new application**

step 4: Enter application details --> click **create your twitter application** button

step 5:-->Your access token

click **create access token** button it will automatically generate **authentication key** and **authentication secret key**

step 6: Click OAuth tool --> get

Consumer key: 
Consumer secret: 
Access token: 
Access token secret: 
AppId:#######

The Application ID is the number present in your application's info page URL. For example:https://dev.twitter.com/apps/######/oauth The ####### is the app ID number. We need this to look up your application's information in our database.

Comment: but this will work for Video uploading i mean i have seen the example for video uploading i have created the oath and other files but video uploading you have to also create `TwitVidAppID` like posting image on twitter using 'TwitPic'. please read my question properly.

Comment: I tried to use the app-id extracted from URL, the way you mentioned in your replay, but it is still not working with my app. It is giving following error: "Couldn't authenticate via Telly API (Invalid Auth request)"

Comment: do you get any idea? whats wrong here while uploading video on twitter using twitvid.?

Comment: I managed to download your code, compile and run it on device. When I select a video from my library, it starts the upload but upload always fails. Any idea? Thank you for your answer btw.

Comment: twitvid code is perfect but there is missing of TwitVidAppId so that's way you can not execute properly and can not connect with twitter