# How to Upload Video on twitter using twitvid but it is not working

Tags: ios, twitter, oauth-1.0a

I want to upload video on `twitter` and i use `twitvid` [sample code](http://twitvid.pbworks.com/w/file/fetch/61533948/TwitVid%20SDK.zip)

and i also create the app on my account and generate all the tokens and ids that is required in the demo and set in demo but when i execute the code and select the video from library and send request it is going failed with Below error

```
    Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo=0x79e30350 {
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://im.twitvid.com/api/uploadPic, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://im.twitvid.com/api/uploadPic, NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, NSUnderlyingError=0x7b6be260 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found."

}
```

still i'm working on the demo B'coz if demo not work than y i code in actual app.
sample code not working after all i creating the app in twitter developer site and get client,tokens and app id and set it in the sample code but still it will give above error Y? that i don't know.

If any one done this plese give me any suggession.

Comment: Sample Code Link is not available

Comment: Check this [how to upload video on twitter using twitvid in iphone sdk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066213/how-to-upload-video-on-twitter-using-twitvid-in-iphone-sdk)

Comment: hey friend @Ashish Kakkad i already doing all that things and i wrote in question also.

Comment: brother I also don't know about it, just giving you path. may you get help.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the provided error, it looks like the URL you are using is wrong.

Comment: in my code i'm not specified any URLs it autometically taken from lib or if U sharp in network issues than please download sample code and please help me

Comment: B'coz i'm not able to get the problem still.